# Reactor simply not reacting

Tags: reactor

With `reactor-core 1.1.4-RELEASE` i tried below but nothing printed out. What should I have missed?

```java
Reactor reactor = Reactors.reactor(new Environment());
reactor.on(
        $("hello"),
        (Event<String> ev) -> System.out.println("hello "
                + ev.getData()));
reactor.notify("hello", Event.wrap("world"));
```

**@EDIT**

Test below confirms that the receiver daemon thread could quit before processing the event.

```java
Reactor reactor = Reactors.reactor(new Environment());
reactor.on($("hello"), (Event<String> ev) -> {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
    System.out.println("hello " + ev.getData());
});
reactor.notify("hello", Event.wrap("world"));
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the extent of your program and there is nothing to prevent the system from exiting until the event is handled then your notify won't have had time to complete before the system will simply exit.

You need a `CountDownLatch` or a `Thread.sleep(1000)` to allow the system time to propagate the event from one Thread to the other.